# How to add 50,000 Products in Laravel Database product table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a MySQL query that contains 50,000 products I  insert 10 products from SQL query but It is not showing in the Admin panel.

I am new in laravel

How to display this laravel model MySQL query

```
$productList = (new ShopProduct)
            ->leftJoin($tableDescription, $tableDescription . '.product_id', $tableProduct . '.id')
            ->where($tableProduct . '.store_id', session('adminStoreId'))
            ->where($tableDescription . '.lang', sc_get_locale());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller function should looks like this:

```
$products = Product::all(); // Fetch rows from Product Model
return view('yourviewfilename', array('products' => $products)); // taking products object to your view file
```

How you need to show on the view file:

```
@foreach ($products as $item)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$item->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: How to echo mysql query like "select *...."   in model

Comment: `$results = \DB::select("SELECT * FROM users");`

By this way you can use custom query in Laravel

Comment: In there any code to display query for above code (I write in my question)

Comment: are you looking for a query log ??? means you are looking for the generated queries... right ????

Comment: Yes I am looking for query log . where I can see query log

Comment: see I had added a answer as a new one... check that it's that you are looking for....

Answer (score 0):

First you have to enable query log it can be done using

```
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
```

then you can use below code to see the query log

```
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
```

if you want to see the last executed query

```
$last_query = end($queries);
```

to know more about logging see this https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging

Example

```
public function show(Order $order){
        \DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
        $data = $order->all();
        $queries = \DB::getQueryLog();
        return dd($queries);
}
```